# How to reload a page without deleting the cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, internationalization, i18next

Im doiing a web app and Im already in the part where theuser has an option to change the language of the app, ex. from en-US to ja, I'm using i18next. What I did was write the user's preferred language to cookie, reload the page, and read the cookie I created with the user's preferred lang. however it doest work because it seems that everytime you reload the page, the cookie that I created is deleted, so it reverts back to the default lang.

The question is there a way to reload the page without deleting the cookie that I made?

Comment: you're probably deleting / emptying the cookie somewhere or not calling it properly... pls post the code you tried...

Comment: Are you setting an expiry date? Could you check your browser's developer tools in the `resources` tab and find out if your cookie's expiry date is set to `session` instead of a proper date in the future.

Comment: @Jorg yes it is set to session. Why? What's the issue regarding that?

Comment: The issue is that a session expires after a reload / closing the browser. If you want the cookie to persist, you'll have to set a date on it. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting an expiry date on the cookie. Code below sets it one year in the future.

```
a = new Date(new Date().getTime() +1000*60*60*24*365);
document.cookie = 'mycookie=somevalue; expires='+a.toGMTString()+';';
```

Please give it a shot and check the `resources` tab again to see if it's changed.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) is some info regarding cookie syntax and options.

Comment: this works! but do I have to worry that the cookie stays in the clients computer for a year?

Comment: Why is that a concern? It means that unless they delete their cookies you'll be able to read their language preference.

Comment: Keep an eye on the recourses tab on big sites like this one. SO sets multiple cookies with huge validity dates

Answer (score 0):

This might happen while development time, once you deploy the app it may not occur.

please deploy the app into local IIS and test it weather you facing same problem.

also hope you added expiry time for cookie. its some thing like below

```
HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("SiteLanguage");
aCookie.Value = "en-US";
aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```